# GitHub pages and relative paths

Tags: html, github

I have created a `gh-pages` branch for a project that I am working on at GitHub.

I use Sublime text to author the website locally and my problem is that when this is pushed to GitHub, all the  links to javascrips, images, and css files are invalid.

For instance, I have this in my head section.

```
<link href="assets/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works great locally, but it does not work from GitHub as the links are not resolved using the repository name as part of the URL.

It asks for:

```
http://[user].github.io/assets/css/common.css
```

when it should have been asking for:

```
http://[user].github.io/[repo]/assets/css/common.css.
```

I could of course put the repo name as part of the URL, but that would prevent my site to work locally during development.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: This happends to me. Did you manage to find out the reason of this?

Comment: Note: in Dec. 2016, GitHub pages has changed considerably. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41127983/6309)

Comment: The problem with relative links in github pages is still there in 2022.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Which browser are you using? Are you sure that this happens? Because it shouldn't. If you include a relative URL in a link, it will get resolved relative to the URL of the document that contains the link. In other words, when you include

```
<link href="assets/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in an HTML document at `http://www.foo.com/bar/doc.html`, the link to `assets/css/common.css` will get resolved by appending it to the prefix of the URL of the HTML document without the last part of the path (without `doc.html`), i.e. the link will resolve to `http://www.foo.com/bar/assets/css/common.css`, not to `http://www.foo.com/assets/css/common.css` as you claim.

For example, view the source of the Twitter Bootstrap webpage: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/. Notice the style links at the top, specified as `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`. That link correctly resolves to `http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css`, i.e. it does include the repo name.

Comment: how do you handle `href="/"` ?

Answer (score 82):

You'll need to [use Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages).

Copying verbatim from the [relevant documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure):

> Sometimes it’s nice to preview your Jekyll site before you push your
>   `gh-pages` branch to GitHub. However, the subdirectory-like URL
>   structure GitHub uses for Project Pages complicates the proper
>   resolution of URLs. Here is an approach to utilizing the GitHub
>   Project Page URL structure (`username.github.io/project-name/`) whilst
>   maintaining the ability to preview your Jekyll site locally.
>
> 1. In `_config.yml`, set the `baseurl` option to `/project-name` – note the leading slash and the absence of a trailing slash.
> 2. When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl}}/path/to/css.css` – note the slash immediately following
>      the variable (just before “path”).
> 3. When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` – note that there is no slash between
>      the two variables.
> 4. Finally, if you’d like to preview your site before committing/deploying using `jekyll serve`, be sure to pass an empty
>      string to the `--baseurl` option, so that you can view everything at
>      `localhost:4000` normally (without /project-name at the beginning):
>      `jekyll serve --baseurl ''`
>
> This way you can preview your site locally from the site root on
>   localhost, but when GitHub generates your pages from the `gh-pages`
>   branch all the URLs will start with `/project-name` and resolve
>   properly.

(Apparently someone figured this out [only a few months ago](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/332#issuecomment-18952908).)

Comment: Yea, this one should be the accepted answer. Seems a bit convoluted for a common Jekyll use case - I wonder if there's a reason they don't use site.baseurl by default?

Comment: While this is several years old and the documentation has changed, this solution worked for me over what was recommended in the Jekyll docs of using `{{ site.github.url }}`

Answer (score 12):

You could just put this

```
<base href="/[repo]/">
```

inside of the `<head>` tag, and it solves the problem.

You could also improve this solution by setting:

```
<base href="{{site.baseurl}}" />
```

and then set `site.baseurl` to empty string for the local testing.

Comment: If you don't want to fool around with Jekyll and all that, this is the best solution

Comment: thanks! but can you give some reference? especially about this `site.baseurl`? i mean, can i access this `site` from console?

Comment: <base href="/[repo]/"> works on pages, but not on localhost I think.

Comment: I still want to find a way to use localhost and pages for the same code but not using Jekyll. Your first solution is for remote.

Answer (score 5):

This should not be an issue anymore in Dec. 2016, 3 and an half years later.
See "[Relative links for GitHub pages](https://github.com/blog/2290-relative-links-for-github-pages)", published by [Ben Balter](https://github.com/benbalter):

> You've been able to use relative links when authoring Markdown [on GitHub.com for a while](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files).

(that is from January 2013)

> Now, those links will continue to work when published via [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).
>
> If you have a Markdown file in your repository at `docs/page.md`, and you want to link from that file to `docs/another-page.md`, you can do so with the following markup:

```
[a relative link](another-page.md)
```

> When you view the source file on GitHub.com, the relative link will continue to work, as it has before, but now, when you publish that file using GitHub Pages, the link will be silently translated to `docs/another-page.html` to match the target page's published URL.
>
> Under the hood, we're using the open source [**Jekyll Relative Links**](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links) plugin, which is activated by default for all builds.
>
> Relative links on GitHub Pages also take into account custom permalinks (e.g., `permalink: /docs/page/`) in a file's YAML front matter, as well as prepend project pages' base URL as appropriate, ensuring links continue to work in any context.

And don't forget that [since August 2016, you can publish your pages right from the `master` branch](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing) (not always the `gh-pages` branch)

And since [Dec. 2016](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3), you don't even need `Jekyll` or `index.md`. [Simple markdown files are enough.](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3)

Comment: There is much good information in your answer - thank you. But after reading through all of the linked articles, I remain at a loss to understand why the relative links in a `html table` in my .md file are not converted to .html during the github pages process. I.e. inside my .md file is an html table containing relative links to other .md files in my repo. The table renders properly on github.com, but in github pages the relative links remain as .md files. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671021/github-pages-fails-to-convert-md-in-table-to-html)

Comment: @Seamus I never saw that kind of conversion within html elements (like table). I assumed the relative link was converted only when used a pure markdown page, not in a mixed of markdown and HTML elements.

Comment: Apparently that is the case. But it seems I am forced to choose between an ugly lopsided table, and links that are not converted properly. Any suggestions/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671021/github-pages-fails-to-convert-md-in-table-to-html)?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Github Pages is not very responsive. Though it makes new files available immediately, modified files would not appear immediately due to caching or something.

After waiting 15 minutes or so, everything is fine.

Comment: THis was the case for me as well

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus: It seems upvotes are not very responsive either  :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a new repo specifically for the github.io webpages. If you name the repo as `[user].github.io` on github then it will be published at `https://[user].github.io` and you can [avoid having the repo name in the URL path completely](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages). Obviously the downside is that you can only have 1 repo like this per github user, so it may not suit your needs, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is now the `relative_url` filter:

```
<link href="{{ '/assets/css/common.css' | relative_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I think the filter relative-Url is a Jekyll example, but you should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem but with an extra complication - some of the URLs to static content appear in templates, that are included all over the site. The `<base href="/[repo]/">` solution only applies to relative URLs, not ones that are path absolute i.e., start with `/` and are 'relative' to the root URL. But making those URLs relative doesn't work either, because I'm just doing basic rendering with Jinja, not using a full build system like Jekyll. So the relative paths are incorrect on the rendered pages.

It seems like the simplest solution is to just set up a custom domain for the page. With a custom domain, the repo name is not appended to the URL, and everything just works