# customizing code snippets in markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to achieve something like this,

[image]

This is a screenshot from some digital ocean tutorial.

I want some colored variables using markdown in code snippets AND that header in which the file name is appearing. Is it possible ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: You mean syntax highlight?

Comment: like that "My First Node" is in red, and that whole text is in a code snippet. I want to know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tables containing inline code snippets.

In GitHub markdown:

```
| My Code                   |
|:-------------------------:|
| `int main() { return 0; }`|
```

Renders as:
[image: preview]

I hope this answered your question!

EDIT: There is also syntax highlighting, like YAML. To do that, you add the language after the ticks like so:

````
```bash
$ echo "hello world"
```
````

That will render as:
[image: syntax highlighting]

Edit 2: Here is the link for the supported language highlighting keywords: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about that ``` thing. But can I get custom colors by that table way?

Comment: It depends what flavor of markdown. On GitHub, I believe that you can use the table OR the syntax highlighting, not both.

Comment: This related comment might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36287428/8122577