# How to put colored text into githubs README.md or Index.md file

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I want to put colored text onto my readme/index.md file but I can't find any way online to do it so it works properly, is it possible, and if so how?

Note: I know there is another similar post but it's a very old post and I tried some of those methods they put, but all of them resulted in either it not working properly or working but with extra things showing such as the + sign etc

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file.

Comment: It's a very old post and I tried some of those methods they put, but all of them resulted in either it not working properly or working but with extra things showing such as the + sign etc. @mattruma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub enabled recently [`README` for user profiles](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-your-profile-readme); which lead to [*a lot*](https://github.com/topics/profile-readme) of [examples](https://github.com/abhisheknaiidu/awesome-github-profile-readme)

**None** of those examples includes colored text!
So as [I mentioned in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23904836/6309), this is *still* not yet for supported by GFM directly.

Comment: Can you link to any specific example with colored text? I don't see any (other than links and emojis). Also your 2014 answer links to the latest Adam-P Markdown cheatsheet, which does not mention color.

Comment: @coolaj86 "Can you link to any specific example with colored text": no, I am afraid I cannot. My answer above is to describe I did not find any example with colors.

Comment: Ah, I see `Note of those ` is a typo for `NONE of those`.

Comment: @coolaj86 Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also: I think by `this is still for` you meant `this is not yet`. Or is only supported in external GFM?

Comment: @coolaj86 That should be clearer indeed. Edited.