# Jekyll on Github pages not displaying images and has broken links

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to host my Jekyll blog on Github pages. The blog is currently live [here](http://ofcan.github.io/sam_yonski/).

As you can see, the images are missing + when you click on the blogposts, it shows 404. How to fix this? [Here's the link](https://github.com/ofcan/sam_yonski/tree/gh-pages) to my public blog repo, and here's my _config.yml file:

```
# Build settings
markdown: redcarpet
highlighter: pygments

# Site settings
title: "Sam Yonski"
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "email:"
Reading and writing...
email: sam.yonski@gmail.com

#blog logo
logo: "/assets/images/sam_yonski_logo.png"

# blog cover
cover: "/assets/images/cA4aKEIPQrerBnp1yGHv_IMG_9534-3-2.jpg"

name: 'Sam Yonski'
author: 'Sam Yonski'
author_image: "/assets/images/author.jpg"
paginate:   5

url: "https://ofcan.github.io" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
baseurl: "/sam_yonski"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In _config.yml set `baseurl: /sam_yonski`

and call you resources with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/css.css">
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/scripts.js"></script>
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/img/toto.jpg">
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/linkto/">Link</a>
```

See [Jekyll documentation here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure)

Comment: This is spot on, but It would be nice to include some additional context on why this is the solution, e.g. GH pages paths include the project name. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19173888/1048479) answer is a great reference

Comment: The real solution is that people RTFM. My answer is short because I'm a little bit bored [to answer the same question again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1548376%20[jekyll]%20site.baseurl)

Comment: @DavidJacquel I also ran into this issue, seems like the manual might need a bit more clarity, as I read it and still wasted some time on this. +1 though as your answers (on multiple questions) have been fantastic guidance in getting jekyll set up and working as I wanted.

Comment: I was about to leave Jekyll and fortunately found this. Thanks

Comment: I tried almost everything this is the only thing that helped which's adding the:
 {{ site.baseurl }}

Answer (score 0):

For me, I went from building the site locally with `.nojekyll` present to having Github Pages build on push.  This broke a handful of my images.  What ended up working was renaming the file, pushing, naming the file back, and then pushing that.

e.g. If `this-image-is-broken.jpg` is not displaying.

1. `this-image-is-broken.jpg` file name is changed to `this-image-is-broken1.jpg`
2. push to Github.
3. `this-image-is-broken1.jpg` file is named back to `this-image-is-broken.jpg`
4. push to Github.

Should be fixed.