# Image does not show up on Github hosted Jekyll blog

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I created my first Jekyll blog using the "Minimal Mistakes" theme.
It works like a charm when I run it locally using `jekyll serve`.
However, when deploying it on Github, I cannot display some of the images.

The images that are called in my post's front matter or directly in the `_config.yaml` show up just fine. On the other hand the image called in my post using markdown does not show up:

I have tried:

`![caption]("/assets/images/image.jpg"){:class="img-responsive"}` (the default)

and

`![caption]("/assets/images/image.jpg")`

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468951/images-not-displaying-in-github-pages), I double checked the spelling, but it seems alright.

[That post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820917/jekyll-on-github-pages-not-displaying-images-and-has-broken-links) suggest to set a `baseurl` in `_config.yml`. What url should I specify? Is that the url of the Github repo where all my files are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of troubleshooting, it appears that the url should contain the root directory (in my case, a folder named blog).

So `![caption]("/blog/assets/images/image.jpg")` does the trick!