# github pages fails to convert .md in table to .html

Tags: github, html-table, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Markdown tables are rendered in a lopsided fashion, and I've used html coding in a markdown (.md) file to get something that looks reasonable to me. That seems to cause a problem when my .md files are converted to .html `github pages` (jekyll).

It seems that any links (e.g. `somefile.md`) in the html-coded table are not converted to the .html extension; in other words, the link in the `github pages` page is to `somefile.md` instead of `somefile.html`. Following a link then yields a really ugly .md file.

This is an awkward description (`github pages` page = inane). I've created a [version of my README.md file here](https://seamusdemora.github.io/PiFormulae/README_backup.html) that includes both the markdown-coded table, and the html-coded table. If you'll follow that link, the issue will be obvious I think.

I would like to have a table that looks rational (not lopsided), **and** have my links converted properly by `github pages`. Is this possible?