# Can not see profile picture react app when deployed on github

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I deployed my react app to GitHub and its working but not what I expected. When I run the app on the localhost its works perfectly and I can see all the pictures and all the navigation works. After deploy on Github, I can not see anymore the images which were a relative path link to my app and also navigation seems not working. Any hints on how to overcome these issues. Here is react app Github deployed Link- Your site is published at 
https://mjachowdhury.github.io/mjacportfolio/

Comment: check this link : => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316311/github-pages-and-relative-paths

Comment: @Amir REzvani - I look into your link did not get any fruitful answer with my issues.