# Gh-pages relative path not found

Tags: image, svg, github-pages, relative-path

Hello i try to deploy my second project website on gh-pages it's seems working but all of my images are not showing, i try different path but still not working i'm new on GitHub hope to fixed it soon thank you.

here is my website repo https://github.com/rcode321/rafaelmendozasite

Answer (score 1):

Check first if using [relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325664/6309) is enough in your [`gh-pages` `index.html` file](https://github.com/rcode321/rafaelmendozasite/blob/b53aee6e78b90b8a8627fdd62559314a192469bd/index.html)

```
<img class="my-image main" src="img/mypix2.jpg" alt="">
instead of
<img class="my-image main" src="/dist/img/mypix2.jpg" alt="">
```

The [OP raffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7654348/raffy) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047259/gh-pages-relative-path-not-found/63047493#comment111492472_63047493):

```
<img class="my-image main" src="./img/mypix2.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: i treid the first approach which is <img class="my-image main" src="img/mypix2.jpg" alt="">
but nothing happens. could that posiible to use the raw file in the src?

Comment: @raffy I don't see any new commits in https://github.com/rcode321/rafaelmendozasite/tree/gh-pages. Only the gh-pages branch is involved for GitHub pages in your case. Modifying files in master won't have any impact.

Comment: thanks it's works i only add ./ on the path. but i'm wondering why some of the images works instantly after i change only the https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjzg47353dhqjrq/path.JPG?dl=0
and the rest of images path are not.?
BTW thanks to your help VonC it's working now.

Comment: @raffy Maybe a cache issue on GitHub side?

Comment: have no idea, but it seems working fine now. but i dunno if this gonna be an issue in the near future. what do you think? is this i need to worry?