# Why my images are not displaying in my Git Hub Pages?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I`ve just built this github pages however for some reason my images are not being loading with the page.

Here is the link of [my site](https://rafaelmspu2.github.io/Projeto-Poli-Junior/projeto%20poli%20junior/)

And here is my [repo](https://github.com/rafaelmspu2/Projeto-Poli-Junior)

Notice that I put all my images inside a doc called "_imagens", and I correctly call it in my.

Anyway here is where I call my images

On the first page:

```
/*Configuracoes da imagem de fundo*/
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) ,url("_imagens/fundo.jpg");    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;

    height: 100vh;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}
```

On second page:

```
<header id="cabecalho">
            <img src="_imagens/poli.png" width="75px"  id="poli">
            <h1>
                Notas Poli
            </h1>
            <img src="_imagens/chapeu.png" width="75px" id="chapeu">
        </header>
```

They did work fine in my computer, so I think that is something that I did on github, but I don't know what could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned before [using a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63047493/6309), so try:

```
<img src="./_imagens/chapeu.png" width="75px" id="chapeu">
```

Or

```
<img src="./projeto poli junior/_imagens/chapeu.png" width="75px" id="chapeu">
```