# CSS and images do not work on GitHub pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages

In localhost, my HTML connects to my CSS file and can read my images but not on GitHub pages.

Why? Am I referencing it wrong for GitHub pages?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/loan_sharks_page.css">
<img src="/assets/img/LS_icon.png" width="300" height="300" />
```

I have also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/loan_sharks_page.css">
    <img src="./assets/img/LS_icon.png" width="300" height="300" />
```

And I have tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loan_sharks_page.css">
        <img src="assets/img/LS_icon.png" width="300" height="300" />
```

Each time I pushed to GitHub, I waited an hour cause I know GitHub pages sometimes takes a while. All of these work on localhost but not on Github pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub pages and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316311/github-pages-and-relative-paths) Also  note that path names are case sensitive,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you can't upload a folder for images. Therefore your source for the image won't work. I put all images and HTML file at same hierarchy level and it worked fine for me.
for example,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

type in your GitHub page URL on the browser followed by `/index.html` that should work.

If not check your href on your Html file & make sure it is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `/` before the path and make sure that you have the same folder and file name. It should be working without any problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/loan_sharks_page.css">
```

Comment: I did its the third example

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub url?

Answer (score 0):

My page uses this code in the layout:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">`

Next to the index.md (meaning the same folder level) file which includes the layout I have such folder structure:

`assets/css/main.css`

The slash (/) in front let the page search from the base folder.

My background image (also set in the css file) uses the slash, too (/assets/images/my_background_image.jpg).

My config.yml file defines `baseurl: ""` - this could also be an issue with your site.

See https://github.com/cadamini/cadamini.github.io

Find some more options to solve the issue in this SO post:
[GitHub pages and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316311/github-pages-and-relative-paths)