# GitHub Pages can't find css and bundle files althogh everything works well locally and on a custom domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

GitHub Pages can't find css and bundle files althogh everything works well locally and on a custom domain. **I deploy from a branch.**

Here's the page -
[GitHubPages page](https://annaantonovna.github.io/HouseLoaderPage/)

The project - [HouseLoaderPage](https://github.com/AnnaAntonovna/HouseLoaderPage)

I have also made a [clone](https://github.com/AnnaAntonovna/HouseLoader) of the project to demostrate that it works well on a custom domain -
[CustomDomain](https://annabaranova.com/)

it look for css and here: [*https://annaantonovna.github.io/styles.css* and *https://annaantonovna.github.io/bundle.js*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKEVb.png)

I'm about to start crying, honestly. I'm a civil engineer - not a programmer.

I tried to change branch to None, waited and switched back - it didn't work. I changed adresses in index.html to links of css files and bundle files on github - it did not work as well. I changed adresses to different variantions of './', '../..' and so on - it did not help as well.

**UPD:** It helped to add the name of a project in a path to files in this strict format `/HouseLoaderPage/styles.css` and `/HouseLoaderPage/bundle.js`. The first "/" was crucial. Surely it does not work locally anymore but at least it works on GitHub pages!:)

Comment: Is it out of the question to change your URLs to `HouseLoaderPage/styles.css` and `HouseLoaderPage/bundle.js`? I know it's not the answer you want, but that will point to the correct files at least. This is quite peculiar. I don't think I've ever seen a page not respect relative URLs.

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316311/github-pages-and-relative-paths).

Comment: I think I can consider anything that might make it work on gitHub pages. So thank you for a suggestion - I have changed urls to HouseLoaderPage/styles.css and HouseLoaderPage/bundle.js. Interesting that it has been trying to deploy it for 12 minutes after the change and finally returned a failure.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your Github pages setup in the original repo.

The two repos have different index.html paths.

- Original - https://annaantonovna.github.io/HouseLoaderPage/
- Clone - https://annabaranova.com/

Notice the extra `HouseLoaderPage` in the original link.

This is messing up the paths to find the files, see the network tab in your browser:

[image: Network tab]

The original repo is trying to load files from https://annaantonovna.github.io/styles.css which doesn't exist

However https://annaantonovna.github.io/HouseLoaderPage/styles.css does

To resolve this either:

1. Fix your Github pages setup so that the index path does not include `HouseLoaderPage`
2. Use relative path imports when requesting your styles and bundles
   Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Pathes are different only because I quilcky followed a suggestion from comments on my post. But the html with 'HouseLoaderPage' was not deployed anyway. Here's the dialog:
Q: 'Is it out of the question to change your URLs to HouseLoaderPage/styles.css and HouseLoaderPage/bundle.js?... ' 
A: '...I have changed urls to HouseLoaderPage/styles.css and HouseLoaderPage/bundle.js. Interesting that it has been trying to deploy it for 12 minutes after the change and finally returned a failure.'
Now the code looks as it did and the way you suggest, but does not work sadly

Comment: It seems the browser is cutting off the HouseLoaderPage in the relative path, since the deploy didn't work can you try again with the `HouseLoaderPage/styles.css` path originally?

Comment: Yes! You gave me idea to try to add "/" before "HouseLoaderPage/" and suddenly it worked. Of course now the local server has a path problem, but I'm not planning to come back to it, so it's a result! Why it worked -  still a big mistery for me! Also I'm sorry this is my first day here, so I do not have reputation to mark your answer as useful, but thank you very much!